# Line follower robot program

Tags: c, line-following

I am working on a line follower robot as part of my Microelectronics project, and am confused over what sort of code to use to program the "pic18f" microcontroller I'm using. Can someone give me source code or a layout of the code and what should be in there?

Comment: Almost none of the stackexchange websites would encourage a question that "asks for source code". We're here and willing to help you, but not do your work. That said, it would be good if you show your efforts, tell us what you searched, what you found and why they didn't seem good enough or what you are confused about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Basic** source code you could start with. Then you can make it more complex:

```
#define INA_2   10   // This is the left forward control of the robot, I defined each pwm pin that is connected to the arduino
#define INB_2   11   // This is the left backward control of the motor, e.g set this high and INB_1 high and others low you will do a reverse
#define INA_1   5    // This is the right forward control of the motor
#define INB_1   6    // This is the right backward control of the motor

void setup() {              // This is always the 1st void function in an arduino program
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(INA_2, OUTPUT);      // each pwm pin was placed as an output for the program
    pinMode(INB_2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(INA_1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(INB_1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {      // This is a loop shows the sensor and the driver funtion
    sensor();
    driver();
}

void driver()       // This is the driver function, it reads the sensors and drives the motor using pwm signal
{
    int lowVal = 60;          // I did set my sensor low value to be 60 note this is not the lowest value the sensor can go
    int highVal = 300;        // I did set my sensor high value to be 300 note this is not the highest value the sensor can go

    int s0 = analogRead(A0);            // This defines the sensor value s0, it puts the reading of analogread(A0) into s0
    int s1 = analogRead(A1);
    int s2 = analogRead(A2);
    int s3 = analogRead(A3);
    int s4 = analogRead(A4);
    int s5 = analogRead(A5);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((s2 >= highVal) && (s3 >= highVal))    // This is the 1st if statement of the program, it says if s2 and s3 see's a black line robot should move straight at highest speed
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if ((s3 >= highVal) && (s4 >= highVal))
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 240);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if ((s4 >= highVal) && (s5 >= highVal))
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if((s1 >= highVal) && (s2 >= highVal))
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if ((s0 >= highVal) && (s1 >= highVal))
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s0 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s1 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s2 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s3 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 255);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s4 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if(s5 >= highVal)
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
    else if((s0 <= lowVal) && (s1 <= lowVal) && (s2 <= lowVal) && (s3 <= lowVal) && (s4 <= lowVal) && (s5 <= lowVal)) // This says if its all white light the robot should make a 180 degree left turn
    {
        analogWrite(INA_2, 0);
        analogWrite(INB_2, 200);
        analogWrite(INA_1, 200);
        analogWrite(INB_1, 0);
    }
}

void sensor(){               // This function basically prints the sensor reading so you can see what sensors are working.
    int s0 = analogRead(A0);
    int s1 = analogRead(A1);
    int s2 = analogRead(A2);
    int s3 = analogRead(A3);
    int s4 = analogRead(A4);
    int s5 = analogRead(A5);

    Serial.print("s0 ");    // This prints out the reading for each sensor
    Serial.print(s0);
    Serial.print(" s1 ");
    Serial.print(s1);
    Serial.print(" s2 ");
    Serial.print(s2);
    Serial.print(" s3 ");
    Serial.print(s3);
    Serial.print(" s4 ");
    Serial.print(s4);
    Serial.print(" s5 ");
    Serial.print(s5);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.println();
}
```